# ¿En qué consiste la actividad de un moderador ♦ de SOes?

Tags: soporte, moderación, moderadores

Estos días estamos atareados con la preparación de las elecciones: prenominaciones, recopilación de preguntas para hacerles, sondeos de idoneidad...

Si bien *Una teoría de la moderación* muestra la filosofía de esta actividad, también es cierto que lo que hace un *moderador ♦* nos es oscuro en algunas ocasiones y seguro que hay cosas que se nos escapan.

Dado que los que se postulen a *moderador ♦* estarán embarcándose en una tarea intensa, creo bueno saber con el máximo detalle de qué se trata exactamente.

Por tanto, ¿podrían los actuales *moderadores ♦* dar algunos datos de su trabajo actual?

Puesto que es difícil saber cómo cuantificar el trabajo, se me ocurren algunas métricas:

- número de reportes diarios que se gestionan
- número de usuarios contactados personalmente, ya sea a través de chat privado o de mensaje
- número de "escalaciones" realizadas, es decir, acciones que ha habido que pedir que gestione un empleado de Stack Exchange (entiendo que Juan M), del tipo unir usuarios o cosas así
- número de usuarios suspendidos, eliminados...
- cómo se organizan los moderadores entre sí y cuál es el vínculo con el CM en el día a día (chat abierto constante, Slack, email...)

Comment: @Rubén añádelos si quieres, me parece bien. Yo no voy a hacerlo porque estoy con eñ móvil y antes me muerdo el pie que encuentro el rombo

Comment: Debo reconocer que tengo mucha curiosidad por conocer los datos que menciona fedorqui. Pero también pienso que pueden llevar a los mismos errores que el medir el trabajo de un desarrollador por el número de líneas de código que escribe. Quien leyese esos números debe tener presente que hay reportes que cuestan el mismo esfuerzo para resolverlos que otros 100 reportes más sencillos. Y que hay esfuerzos que no están representados en eso números. Teniendo eso en cuenta me parece una información interesante y útil.

Comment: Aunado a lo que menciona @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, si un moderador ♦ debe hacer lo menos posible, según una teoría de moderación, ¿cómo se mide las ocasiones que está atento sin hacer nada, otras palabras, disponible? como los bomberos o los médicos de urgencias. Me respondo a mi mismo, cual es el tiempo que pasa entre que se reclama la atención de un moderador ♦ para un caso típico y que se concluye/resuelve.

Comment: @Jose buena observación. Claro, no todos los reportes son iguales y contactar con un usuario piede consumir más esfuerzo y neuronas que gestionar diez reportes. Pero creo que algún número ayuda para tener una idea de las magnitudes y necesidades. Me interesa especialmente la conexión moderadores-CM y la forma de organizarse.

Comment: @Rubén esa también puede ser una métrica (que los moderadores vemos en forma de "tiempo medio de gestión de reportes"). Creo que lo de _un moderador de la comunidad debe hacer lo menos posible_ es cierto, pero también es obvio que hay cosas que solo él puede hacer. Mi pensamiento respecto esa frase es que debe dejar a la comunidad autogestionarse lo más posible, intercediendo solamente en casos puntuales y necesarios. Pero luego hay un montón de trabajo de fondo, silencioso y no visible al resto de usuarios, que merece ser explicado.

Comment: Hay que ver qué piensa Luiggi. De todos modos, creo que a él no le interesan los números.

Comment: @ArtEze a mí tampoco me quitan el sueño los números, pero considero útil que se comparta algún tipo de métrica para que los que se postulen (y la comunidad) puedan tener una idea de la tarea que acometéis diariamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dejo la estadística, un poco apresurada.

- Reportes en un trimestre: 3.172

  - Para hacer el cálculo de los reportes diarios, lo divido por 91 días.
  - Reportes diarios: 34
  - Para hacer, diarios por moderador, somos 3 moderadores, sin incluir a Miquel Coll.
  - Diarios por moderador: 11
- Mensajes enviados por moderadores en el trimestre: 54

  - Aquí solo fuimos yo y Luiggi, mientras que fredyfx no. Cada uno en promedio: 27, es decir 1 cada 3 días por moderador.

Lo demás no lo sé con certeza, o no investigué lo suficiente. Los moderadores tenemos una habitación especial en el chat. En fin, espero haber resuelto en parte tus dudas.

Comment: No son 4 moderadores, sin contar a Miquel: Luigi, fedorqui, fredyfx y tu? 34 reportes diarios entre 4 da a 8.5.

Comment: @toledano: fedorqui no es moderador en SOes, todavía ;) Referencia: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ArtEze por la respuesta. Se confirma que curráis muchísimo, ¡gracias por vuestro tiempo y disposición! @futuros-moderadores: fium, aquí hay trabajo :)

Comment: O_o lo hubiera jurado

Comment: Gracias @ArtEze por la información! Qué bueno que estés dando respuesta a esto. Pregunta: con "mensajes", ¿qué estás incluyendo?

Comment: @Mariano Todos los mensajes de moderador a los usuarios, ya sea con o sin suspensión. Estos se deben usar cuando hay alguna anomalía con los usuarios.

Comment: @ArtEze entiendo, por lo que no se incluyen comentarios en publicaciones, conversaciones de chat ni e-mails?

Comment: @Mariano Exacto, no se incluyen.

Comment: @ArtEze gracias!

Comment: @Mariano los moderadores tienen una tabla de resumen de todos ellos que indica las acciones que ha hecho/gestionado cada uno: reportes, comentarios, publicaciones... Los [mensajes de moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-messages) se envían a través de una interfaz específica que contiene distintas plantillas predeterminadas (opcionales) y permite suspender a la vez que se escribe.

Comment: Hasta el momento siempre dejo comentario en vez de utilizar dicha interfaz, ¡Gracias por el dato! lo tendré en cuenta :D