# ¿En qué consiste la actividad de un moderador ♦ de SOes en 2019?

Tags: soporte, moderación, moderadores

Para las elecciones de 2017 planteé por aquí la pregunta [¿En qué consiste la actividad de un moderador ♦ de SOes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2415/83) para conocer qué carga de trabajo aproximada tiene un moderador en su día a día. Así, pensé, ayudarían a que los candidatos tuvieran más conocimiento de dónde se metían :) El por entonces moderador ArtEze dio algunos números que creo que ayudaron a tener una visión

Este año lo empezamos con el tremendo [2018: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3850/83) con un montón de datos. La mayor parte de los datos que dio ArtEze entrarían en esa parte, pero ¿podrían los moderadores dar un resumen similar al de hace dos años, indicando también el volumen de trabajo en Meta? Idealmente también indicaría que tanto por ciento de trabajo se va en cada cosa ("20 minutos con reportes, algún mensaje aquí y allí...").

Veo que este tipo de preguntas se plantea en otras comunidades también: [What’s it like being a Unix & Linux moderator?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5218/40596). Leyéndolas, creo que sería bueno ampliar un poco el foco de lo numérico a lo sustancial:

- ¿Qué representa ser moderador de SOes?
- ¿En qué ocupas el día a día?
- ¿Qué situaciones complejas representa?
- ¿Qué debería tener en cuenta alguien que considera presentarse para el puesto?
- ¿Qué dedicación aproximada requiere? Excluyendo la parte de *uso* del sitio como usuario regular. Y, de hecho, ¿qué tanto por ciento de tu uso del sitio es como moderador?
- ¿Qué cosas te gustaría hacer como moderador y crees que con más manos se podrían hacer?

Answer (score 17):

> ¿Qué representa ser moderador de SOes?

Ser moderador es un puesto de responsabilidad e importancia en el sitio y sobre todo es un **trabajo voluntario**. Pero representa compromiso.

Por eso, a la par que crece el sitio, aumentar el número de moderadores es muy importante. Para poder hacer las cosas cuando quieras o tengas ganas y a la vez no sentirte *mal* porque el sitio queda desatendido.

> ¿En qué ocupas el día a día?

- Suelo empezar el día con un vistazo rápido a las **colas de revisión**. Todas las colas son accesibles por usuarios sin diamante, con más o menos rep, pero cuando se desbordan hay que hacer limpieza.
- Después miro la **lista de reportes de moderador**. Miro aquellos que los otros mods no han interferido primero y cuando acabo miro los que llevan un tiempo para ver su evolución.

  Esta sección es la que más problemas (de decisión, principalmente) suele dar. Aquí hay casos tan sencillos como un reporte de comentario obsoleto, hasta reportes complejos como posibles [cuentas títere](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%C3%B3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%C3%ADtere-en-stack-exchange). Reportes como estos pueden llevar mucho tiempo de decisión, ya que has de investigar muchas cosas en diferentes días para ver el panorama de manera más global. También entra el hablar con el resto de mods tanto de este sitio como en el chat global de moderadores.
- El resto del día es revisar los dos puntos anteriores puntualmente (la lista de reportes de mod sale como un numero al lado de tu perfil en la cabecera de la página y si el número se dispara es fácil notarlo), mirar de vez en cuando las publicaciones recientes para orientar a usuarios nuevos y **estar pendiente del chat** donde muchas situaciones se publican ahí primero.
- Y a parte de todo eso está Meta. Por suerte, nos llega una notificación cuando una nueva metapregunta es formulada. Las dudas generales de usuarios las suelen contestar otros usuarios, si es que no están contestadas ya.
  Luego habría que hacer ciertas tareas como las peticiones de crear/aprobar sinónimos, y demás procedimientos en masa que a veces se requieren.

> ¿Qué situaciones complejas representa?

Como explico en el punto anterior, hay casos que llevan tiempo y son complejos.

Por ejemplo, hay una situación que sigue dejándome mal sabor de boca. Cuando **un usuario nuevo publica una pregunta de baja calidad**, trato de explicarle qué tiene mal y cómo mejorarlo (si es que la pregunta es salvable) y el usuario hace caso omiso de mis recomendaciones. Sin embargo, sí que responde a gente que le hace otro tipo de comentarios.

Aquí **me pregunto si debo cerrarla inmediatamente**, para curarnos en salud ante futuras respuestas, o no hacerlo por ser algo unilateral además que el usuario podría abrumarse ante el cambio de estado de su primera pregunta. En caso de cerrarla, o se mejora y se reabre o se queda en el olvido hasta que es eliminada. En caso de dejarla abierta puede pasar que se edite y mejore o que no mejore nada y que además reciba respuestas.

En las respuestas suelo comentar que **es de agradecer que quiera ayudar** al usuario, **pero es mejor esperar** a que el autor de la pregunta la mejore. A veces porque la respuesta está basada en suposiciones que el autor de la pregunta ha de aclarar. Otras, porque le está resolviendo una tarea que, a priori, el autor de la pregunta ni ha intentado. Y es que pedir deberes/ejercicios en SOes es algo que me afecta bastante.

> ¿Qué debería tener en cuenta alguien que considera presentarse para el puesto?

**Es muy importante tener siempre una razón** o motivo objetivo al realizar cualquier acción.

Si en cualquier momento tus emociones humanas (los moderadores no somos robots) interfirieran en el resultado de una acción has de parar inmediatamente. Deja el reporte a un lado y toma un descanso o coméntalo con otro mod para que se encargue.

> ¿Qué dedicación aproximada requiere? Excluyendo la parte de uso del sitio como usuario regular. Y, de hecho, ¿qué tanto por ciento de tu uso del sitio es como moderador?

Como decía, es voluntario. **El tiempo requerido es el tiempo del que dispongas y quieras emplear**. Una hora todos los días sería más que perfecto si la disponibilidad lo permite.

Por mi parte, casi todo mi uso del sitio es dedicado a moderar. Publico muy pocas respuestas y aún menos preguntas aunque sí que dejo muchos comentarios *"de usuario normal"*.

---

## Métricas

En el último año hemos tenido **11.762 reportes** con una media de resolución de **14h**.

Puede que esta cifra de tiempo asuste pero como indico en la primera parte de la respuesta, hay muchos reportes que no puedes resolverlos en el acto si no que tienes que dejar un comentario para que el usuario mejore la publicación, investigar, comentar con otros mods o comunicarte con usuarios de manera privada.

---

Tras este tiempo como moderador he visto muchos usuarios que se han esforzado un montón en que el sitio sea lo mejor que puede ser. Cuidan de *sus etiquetas*, están pendientes de meta, moderan muy activamente con sus privilegios y están al tanto de nuevas funcionalidades que poder implementar y usar en el sitio.

**Estoy muy agradecido por su ayuda. Gracias**

Comment: Fantástica respuesta y qué fantástico tenerte de moderador. Cabal, educado y competente. ¡Mil gracias a ti!

Comment: gracias, @fedorqui. Por tus palabras y ayuda en el sitio. Y creo que es la primera vez que me llaman *cabal* ^^'

Comment: Para completar lo mismo también sería útil algún número, como dio ArtEze: reportes diarios, tiempo medio de resolución... Lo digo por mera curiosidad, pues por ejemplo el sitio que yo modero apenas tiene 2-3 reportes al día.

Comment: @fedorqui añadi un par de datos del ultimo año

Answer (score 10):

> ¿Qué representa ser moderador de SOes?

Sé que esto va a sonar confuso, pero ser moderador se siente a veces como algo contradictorio: es un privilegio y un honor pero también un deber; algo voluntario pero que requiere compromiso y dedicación; una bendición y también un poco una maldición.

Tener acceso a las diferentes herramientas de moderación, y con ellas tener la habilidad de ayudar al sitio y crecer con la comunidad, es maravilloso. Pero hay que hacer uso de esas herramientas y ayudar a la comunidad a crecer... a veces a costa del crecimiento propio.

Supongo que se puede resumir en la frase que repiten en cada película de Spiderman: "con un gran poder viene una gran responsabilidad".

> ¿En qué ocupas el día a día?

Principalmente revisando las herramientas del moderador. Viendo los reportes que los usuarios han creado e intentado actuar sobre ellos lo antes posible, antes de que se acumulen.

También visito las colas de revisión. Intento no actuar a no ser que sea un caso claro por aquello de que el voto de un moderador es vinculante, aunque si veo que el número de publicaciones a revisar es muy alto bajo un poco el listón y entro más en acción (p.e. en algunos casos le doy a "Omitir" a menos que haya 4 votos, pero si la cola es muy grande -como lo es ahora- puede que vote cuando haya 2-3 usuarios que hayan votado de la misma manera que yo lo haría).

Dos cosas que me gustaría hacer más de lo que hago es pasarme por el chat (aunque intento pasarme a menudo, no soy muy consistente) y estar más activo en meta (entro y leo las publicaciones pero no interactúo tanto como antes).

> ¿Qué situaciones complejas representa?

Se trata con personas, no con máquinas. Hay que estar atento y tener eso en cuenta en todo momento. Y la mayor *complejidad* viene de ahí: cada persona es un mundo, y en este sitio hay personas que vienen de diferentes lugares, con diferentes experiencias y diferentes ambientes sociales.

A menudo lo único que compartimos es el idioma español y la pasión por la informática... e incluso aunque todos hablemos español, a veces parece como si no estuviéramos usando el mismo idioma.

> ¿Qué debería tener en cuenta alguien que considera presentarse para el puesto?

Ser moderador requiere paciencia y [tener mucha mano izquierda](https://spaniway.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/frases-tener-mano-izquierda/). Hay que saber cuándo hay que cumplir las normas a rajatabla y cuando las normas se pueden estirar un poco; principalmente con los usuarios nuevos, a los que hay que guiar y no espantar.

Las decisiones que tomes no van a gustar a todo el mundo... pero eso es normal. Si puedes justificar la decisión que has tomado, siempre vas a tener gente (y moderadores) para apoyarte.

Vas a encontrar usuarios que lleven la contraria y busquen problemas... y eso también es normal. Más de una vez (y más de dos) esos usuarios van a probar tu paciencia para ver dónde están los límites. Es importante para un moderador tener la cabeza serena y no tomárselo como algo personal. Otros usuarios (y moderadores) van a estar ahí para apoyarte.

> ¿Qué dedicación aproximada requiere? Excluyendo la parte de uso del sitio como usuario regular. Y, de hecho, ¿qué tanto por ciento de tu uso del sitio es como moderador?

Realmente, no requiere una dedicación mayor de la que ya estés teniendo en el sitio (dependiendo de tu actividad). Lo que sí va a requerir es un ajuste sobre las acciones que se realizarían normalmente.

Moderar puede quitar tiempo para otras actividades "normales" del sitio. Desde que soy moderador paso más tiempo moderando que contestando (lo cual tampoco tiene un impacto muy grande en el sitio porque las etiquetas por las que más me movía tienen muchos usuarios) o preguntando.

Antes de ser moderador usaba 80% de mi tiempo para responder y 20% en actividades de moderación (colas de revisión, comentarios, etc). Ahora el tiempo se ha invertido y paso mucho más tiempo moderando (80-90%) que en otras actividades.

> ¿Qué cosas te gustaría hacer como moderador y crees que con más manos se podrían hacer?

Me gustaría tener algo *más de control sobre el sitio* tanto como usuario como moderador. Sé que esto es más cosa de Nicolas y Juan, pero me gustaría intentar realizar actividades que aumenten el compromiso y la actividad (especialmente de nuevos usuarios).

Más moderadores significaría compartir las tareas, menos tiempo moderando y más tiempo actuando como usuario normal o la posibilidad de asistir en esas actividades.

Comment: Tenía esta respuesta a medio redactar desde ayer... me ha llevado más tiempo del esperado terminarla.

Comment: Es una buena respuesta, y da una idea bastante ajustada de lo que supone ser mod en el sitio. Gracias Alvaro

Comment: Gran respuesta, Alvaro. Da gusto ver que siempre tienes en cuenta el factor humano y actúas con la máxima de "menos es más" como moderador. ¡Qué suerte tenemos teniéndote de moderador!